# Creating an entity with a M:N relationship with sequelize on postgres

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, promise, sequelize.js

I have basically two main models Country, Activity, that have an M:N relation, so I used the following to define a third model Country_Activity

EDIT

```
Country.belongsToMany(Activity, {through: 'Country_Activity',
    foreignKey: 'actId',
    otherKey: 'alpha3Code'
})

Activity.belongsToMany(Country, {through: 'Country_Activity',
    foreignKey: 'actId',
    otherKey: 'alpha3Code'
});
```

Once I create all the Countries, I proceed to create the activities, but this time, indicating the countries in which they are present

```
router.post('/saveacomplexactivity', async(req, res) => {
    console.log('Api::Activities.js (15):: req.body: ', req.body)
    await Activity.create({
        actId: req.body.actId,
        name: req.body.name,
        countries: req.body.countries
    }, {
        include: [Country]
    }).then((activity) => {
        res.json(activity)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

Hoping that it will create, not only the activity but the association in the junction table Country_Activity as well

But it doesn’t work, while the countries and the activities are created, the Country_Activity model is created but remains empty

EDIT

I'm getting an error, saying that there is a violation of the Activities primary key uniqueness (actId duplicate), but is weird, since I'm saving only one Activity. May be the problem is in the definition of the relationship.

I tried interchanging the "foreignKey, otherKey" delaration, with the same result

The way I'm saving to the DB is this, first I save all the countries, each of them into a promise, then I use Promise.All to ensure that I will create the activity after all countries have been created (this way I ensure that I wont be referring a country that hasn't been created yet)

What could I be missing here?

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

```
Country.belongsToMany(models.Activity, {
    foreignKey: 'countryId',
    otherKey: 'activityId',
    through: models.Country_Activity,
    as: 'activity'
})

Activity.belongsToMany(Country, {
    through: 'Country_Activity',
    foreignKey: 'countryId',
    otherKey: 'activityId',
    as: 'country'
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i'll try it in a while

Comment: `countryId`, `activityId` must math with `Country_Activity` 's attributes name

Comment: Does it mean that I have to create Country-Activity first, the documentation says that if I set 'Country_Activity' as a string, it will create the model. I tried it and it didn´t work

Comment: `Country_Activity` is not created automatically

Comment: It is being created automatically, I'm checking in the database, and the documentation says so

Comment: by the way, i created the table with migration/model